# Postman - how to run requests in different iterations

Tags: collections, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase

I have an issue about running a collection
I have the following:
Collection: Request 1
Request 2
Request 3

What I want: When I run collection, I want Request 1 to be executed 20 times, then after iteration 20 to run Request 2 and after Request 2 is done to run Request 3.
So: Request 1 to run 20 times, Request 2 one time, Request 3 one time

I tried something like (In Tests script of Request 1):

```
if (pm.info.iteration === pm.info.iterationCount+3) {
    postman.setNextRequest("Url of request 1")
}
```

But it's running 1:1 like Request 1, Request 2, Request 3, Request 1, 2,3... and so on

Do you have any ideas? #I am new to Postman

Answer (score 1):

My idea is creating a variable `count_num` to manage the loop.

Request 1:

Pre-request: Create `count_num` if there is no `count_num` in environment

```
let count = pm.environment.get("count_num");

if (count === undefined || count === null) {
    pm.environment.set("count_num", 19);
}
```

Test: Check the value of `count_num`, if count_num = 0, then go Request 2.

```
let count = pm.environment.get("count_num");

if (count === 0){
    pm.environment.unset("count_num");
    postman.setNextRequest("Req2");  
} else {
    pm.environment.set("count_num", count - 1);
    postman.setNextRequest("Req1");
}
```

Note: `"Req1"` & `"Req2"` are request name, you can change to fit your actual request name.